i can't create or connect new wifi network connection directly in LightDM login screen, it gives "insufficient privileges" error
I have encountered two scenarios regarding connecting to a new WiFi network directly from the LightDM-KDE-Greeter login screen, and I'm seeking clarification on the feasibility of achieving the desired functionality without prior configuration.
Scenario One: Upon logging into a fresh system with KDE and LightDM-KDE-Greeter, I did not connect to any WiFi networks from the login screen. After logging in, I successfully connected to a WiFi network using nm-applet. I then adjusted the network connection settings to allow all users to connect to this network in the general configuration. Subsequently, upon logging out and returning to the login screen, I was able to connect to the network without encountering any errors. This scenario indicates that the functionality works in LightDM.
Scenario Two: In another instance, upon logging into a fresh system, I attempted to connect to a new WiFi network directly from the login screen without performing the configuration steps described in scenario one. However, I encountered an error stating "insufficient privileges." It's worth noting that if I follow the steps outlined in scenario one (connecting from the desktop environment and adjusting network settings), the connection works without errors at the login screen.
Based on these scenarios, my question is: Is it possible to connect to a new WiFi network directly from the LightDM-KDE-Greeter login screen without first configuring the network connection from the desktop environment?
Your insights and guidance on achieving this functionality would be greatly appreciated.
More info:
Kubuntu 24.04
LightDM version: 1.30.0
KDE Plasma version: 5.27.11
KDE Framework Version: 5.115.0
i tried to change network polkit but it is working.
